# Wpf FlowDocument Refuses to Accept Focus

Tags: c#, wpf, focus, flowdocument

I have tried everything I can think of to get my `FlowDocument` to accept focus whenever the parent `UserControl` is visible:

```
public DesignView()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    IsVisibleChanged += OnIsVisibleChanged;
}

private void OnIsVisibleChanged(object sender, 
    DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
{
    if (Document.Focusable)
    {
        if (!Document.Focus())
        {
            FocusManager.SetFocusedElement(Document, Document);
            Keyboard.Focus(Document);
            Document.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
                DispatcherPriority.Input,
                new ThreadStart(delegate
                {
                    Keyboard.Focus(Document);
                    FocusManager.SetFocusedElement(Document, Document);
                    Document.Focus();
                })
            );
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I've tried `FocusManager.SetFocusedElement()`, `Keyboard.Focus()`, and `Document.Focus()`all with equal degrees of success... and then tried each method in a separate thread, still with no joy.

I'm not trying all of these simultaneously, just trying to illustrate that NONE of these methods is working, despite the fact that `Document.Focusable` is always `true`.

**EDIT**

My goal is to have Keyboard focus in the FlowDocument so that the user can start typing immediately.  Everything is working typing-wise, but I can't get it to have focus as soon as it is shown.

After this, IsFocused is still false, the keyboard focus is *not* in the `FlowDocument`.

Comment: Does IsFocused remain false after this method? If yes do you know what does have focus? If no you can also add a LostFocus handler and reapply it

Comment: I understand well that it is not "working" but I don't understand what do you expect by doing this, a visual change? Explain me the result you are looking for

Comment: @PouyaAbadi I have added edits to better explain my goals.  IsFocused is *never* true as far as I can tell; I do not know what has focus - maybe I can find out.

Comment: @Safe I'm trying to get keyboard focus on the `FlowDocument` so I can start typing as soon as it's presented.

Comment: @William'Scott'Baker I think we need to see your XAML, but from what I can tell you are using FlowDocument whose default data template is FlowDocumentReader which is not for editing the document. You'll have to use a RichTextBox instead

Comment: As @PouyaAbadi said I don't think you focusing the right element and if we can see the xaml code we can maybe help you to find it